# Update changes smoothly of a PyQt widget

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 application that looks like this [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AELLR.png). Now, with the "bailar" button I want the character on the grid to look left and right a couple of times. I do this in the following method:

```
def dance(self):
    """
    Make the P1 dance
    """
    p1 = self._objects['P1']
    x = p1.x
    y = p1.y

    cell = self.worldGrid[y][x]

    for i in xrange(3):
        print("Moving my head...")
        cell.objectLeaves('P1')
        p1.pixmap = p1.pixmap.transformed(QTransform().scale(-1, 1))
        cell.objectArrives('P1', p1)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

However, the label containing the pixmap updates only at the last iteration. I know this must be a problem of the update function being asynchronous and the time.sleep() blocking the main thread, but I don't know how else could I show the animation. I tried using a QThread with the moveToThread method, but it failed as the gird widget is a child of the main window. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably want to use the [Qt animation framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see only the last frame of your animation because the UI isn't updated by Qt until the `dance` function terminates. If you add `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` just before the `time.sleep(0.2)` statement, the UI will be updated for every frame of the animation.

Note that the user still cannot interact with your application until the animation has finished. This might not be a problem for short animations like this, but for longer animations you might better use a `QTimer` or the Qt animation framework that Brendan Abel suggested.